# ReactNative TabBarIOS Undefined

Tags: react-native

Hell, I'm trying to create a tab bar in my react native app, but after importing it, it appears it's always undefined. Has this component been deprecated? I still see it listed in the docs. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tabbarios.html

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  TabBarIOS
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <TabBarIOS/>
        );
    }
}
```

I'm using react-native 0.59.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this has been removed as part of a core cleanup effort. There doesn't appear to be any native alternative that also behaves correctly on tvos.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/02697291ff41ddfac5b85d886e9cafa0261c8b98

I've gone ahead and extracted TabBarIOS out into a native module for anyone looking for this.

https://github.com/modavi/NativeIOS

install instructions:

```
npm install git+https://github.com/modavi/NativeIOS#master
react-native link native-ios
```

Comment: import { TabBarIOS } from 'native-ios'